# Need config file for loading PRISM modules

Tags: wpf, prism

I am trying to use PRISM for my application. I have been following Mike Taulty's video s on the same. I would like to know, if there is any sample code available for app.config file mentioned while loading modules without references. What I mean is I am looking to copy paste the configuration related information, instead of typing them from start to avoid mistakes. Also I would liek to know if the version number of the assembly is needed or not in the config file while we follow this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My ModulesCatalog.xaml looks like this:

```
<Modularity:ModuleCatalog xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
                          xmlns:Modularity="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism">
    <Modularity:ModuleInfoGroup InitializationMode="WhenAvailable">
        <Modularity:ModuleInfo 
            Ref="MyCo.Module.SystemManager.SL.xap"
            ModuleName="MembershipModule" 
            ModuleType="MyCo.Module.SystemManager.Module, MyCo.Module.SystemManager.SL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    </Modularity:ModuleInfoGroup>
    <Modularity:ModuleInfoGroup InitializationMode="OnDemand">
        <Modularity:ModuleInfo 
            Ref="MyCo.Module.Mobile.SL.xap"
            ModuleName="MobileModule" 
            ModuleType="MyCo.Module.Mobile.Module, MyCo.Module.Mobile.SL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        <Modularity:ModuleInfo 
            Ref="MyCo.Module.Dispatch.SL.xap"
            ModuleName="DispatchModule" 
            ModuleType="MyCo.Module.Dispatch.Module, MyCo.Module.Dispatch.SL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        <Modularity:ModuleInfo 
            Ref="MyCo.Module.Assets.SL.xap"
            ModuleName="AssetsModule" 
            ModuleType="MyCo.Module.Assets.Module, MyCo.Module.Assets.SL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    </Modularity:ModuleInfoGroup>
</Modularity:ModuleCatalog>
```

I would also check PRISM samples (in PRISM installation folder)
Version needed, yes